# modify a regex so that only [a-zA-Z] is captured

Tags: javascript, regex, capturing-group

I have the following Regular Expression:
`/i'm [a-zA-Z]|i am [a-zA-Z]*/i`
It works in terms of detecting when a phrase matches the regex, but I'm specifically trying to capture the `[a-zA-Z]` part.
For example:

`"I'm sam" // -> sam
 I am good at this // -> good`

Tell me if this question needs any improvement.
Thanks in advance! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2018, Javascript finally supports lookbehind assertions, so the following should work <s>in latest browsers</s> once it's implemented:

```js
test = "i am sam";

console.log(test.match(/(?<=i'm |i am )[a-zA-Z]+/))
```

UPD: at the time of writing, only Chrome can do that, so this answer is going to be valid in a few months. In the meantime,

```js
test = "i am sam";

console.log(test.match(/(?:i'm |i am )([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1])
```

Comment: You probably want case insensitivity flag on the RegExp, and you have a possible reference error if the match gives `null`

Comment: @PaulS.: CW'ed it, feel free to edit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sorry if my question was a duplicate, I wasn't really sure what to search for in order to check whether it was.

Comment: @BenRivers: no worries, and welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

You could capture your words using a capturing group `([a-zA-Z]+)`:

[`I ?['a]m ([a-zA-Z]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/UkttR7/1)

This would match

```
I          # Match I
 ?         # Match an optional white space
['a]m      # Match ' or a followed by an m and a whitespace
(          # Capture in a group
 [a-zA-Z]+ # Match lower or uppercase character one or more times
)          # Close capturing group
```

Your words are in group 1.

```js
var pattern = /I ?['a]m ([a-zA-Z]+)/;
var strings = [
  "I am good at this",
  "I'm sam"
];

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  console.log(strings[i].match(pattern)[1]);
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter: How can I improve my answer?